# On Android Studio, how to make ArrayList receive info from different activity and display it in a RecyclerView, and make a new row for each input?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I've been stuck on this for a while. Right now when I input information in my input activity, the information gets displayed in the RecyclerView interface. However, when I input information a second time instead of making a 2nd row and displaying the information, it just replaces the original row that was created. I want it so it makes a new row each time new information is inputted. Any suggestions on what to do? This is my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<medicationinfo> mMedInfoList = new ArrayList<medicationinfo>();
    private Button btnaddmed;
    private String med;
    private String time;
    private String pillnumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            med = bundle.getString("medItem");
            time = bundle.getString("timeformed");
            pillnumber = bundle.getString("pillnumber");
        }

        createMedList();
        buildRecyclerView();

        btnaddmed = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        btnaddmed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddMed.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createMedList() {
        mMedInfoList.add(new medicationinfo(med,time,pillnumber));
    }


    public void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new MedicationAdapter(mMedInfoList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the reason this is happening is because in the above activity you receive data from another activity, you create a new list and you use it to populate your adapter with new items. So, when you leave this activity and return, the old data don't exist anymore. And you only show the new data received from the previous activity.

One solution is to store the list with which you set the Adapter in your cache. Then if you leave your  activity and return, you will retrieve the list from your cache and also add to it the new medicationInfo item you create each time and use this fully updated list to set the adapter. Don't forget then to store your updated list again in your cache memory to be able to retrieve these changes later when needed.

I suggest that you take a look into [Room library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using two actiivty one for input and the other one is for showing the data that the reason when ever you call the second activity its create the list again and remove the all data from  the arrayList for this i suggest you to use startActivity for result if you are getting data from second activity to first activity , Or you can store your arrayList data into your local memory like sqlite , Room ,Realm and SharedPrefrence